# Request Structure in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I m working on WSO2 DSS 3.0.0. I m sending request structure via SOAP UI to DSS. I m not getting the expected output.

I want to check what is the request structure query that is hitting DSS.

In short I want to see what Query DSS is forming at runtime.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The request format depends on the data service opertions you have created. Each of these opertion invokes an query. And these queries have input parameters and output parameters. The opertion name + input parameters will determine the format of the request message and the output parameters determine the result format of the message.

You can use the WSDL of the relevant data service for creating the SOAP UI project. Then the request message for each Data Service opertion will be there. Or you can simple try-it the dataservice using available Try-it[1] option for the service. There also you can see the request format for each operation.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS300/Testing+WSDLs